# commit-interval is not working as expected

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Let say,we have 1000 items in DB,and we try to fetch and delete 10 items,at a time.For this We have implemented Spring batch.

As per the below configuration.

```
<batch:chunk reader="tokenReader" writer="tokenWriter" commit-interval="10"></batch:chunk>
```

We have `ItemReader` class,which fetch 10 item at a time from DB and passes list of 10 token to `ItemWriter`.

So after processing 10 items,it should commit ideally.

But we are facing below issue.

With `commit-interval = 10`,JobLauncher is launching 10 threads,and each thread is fetching same 10 tokens from database,and once ItemReader passes list of 10 token to ItemWriter,we receive exception("`The token is already marked to be deleted`" `JPA Exception`).

However if we set `commit-interval = 1`,it starts only `1` thread and execute successfully with fetch and delete 10 items at a time.

Comment: can you post your `taskExecutor` configuration ?

Comment: I have not configured it,i assume it should be default.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30165680/spring-batch-item-reader-is-executing-only-once?

Comment: No,it's different,that problem i have solved by putting "allow-start-if-complete" in tasklet.That problem is solved now.