# Spting cloud data flow batch job is running one time if @EnableTask is used in main app

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-dataflow

Hi I am trying to deploy simple spring boot batch jar file in local spring cloud data flow server. I am facing serious problem in the batch when I am using @EnableTask in my main java class. When I am using @EnableTask in my application the batch job is running only one time. Its executing the batch and then de registering the application automatically. Code for the application is given below.

1)main class

```
package com.jwt.spring.batch;

import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.task.configuration.EnableTask;

@EnableTask
@EnableBatchProcessing
@SpringBootApplication
public class ScdfBatchApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ScdfBatchApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

2)JobConfiguration.java

```
package com.jwt.spring.batch;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepContribution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.ChunkContext;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.Tasklet;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class JobConfiguration {

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(JobConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job").start(stepBuilderFactory.get("jobStep1").tasklet(new Tasklet() {
            @Override
            public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
                logger.info("Job was run");
                return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
            }
        }).build()).build();
    }
}
```

3)pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.jwt.spring.batch</groupId>
    <artifactId>SCDFBatch</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SCDFBatch</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud-task.version>1.2.2.RELEASE</spring-cloud-task.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-task</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-task-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-task.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Below is the log of the application

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.9.RELEASE)

2018-01-05 17:13:37.984  INFO 14436 --- [           main] c.jwt.spring.batch.ScdfBatchApplication  : Starting ScdfBatchApplication on bdc7-l-5065XBS with PID 14436 (C:\STS-WORK_SPACE\SPRING-BATCH\SCDFBatch\target\classes started by mukesh.bo.kumar in C:\STS-WORK_SPACE\SPRING-BATCH\SCDFBatch)
2018-01-05 17:13:37.990  INFO 14436 --- [           main] c.jwt.spring.batch.ScdfBatchApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-01-05 17:13:38.091  INFO 14436 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@9e725a: startup date [Fri Jan 05 17:13:38 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-01-05 17:13:39.153  INFO 14436 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'transactionManager' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.cloud.task.configuration.SimpleTaskConfiguration; factoryMethodName=transactionManager; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in org.springframework.cloud.task.configuration.SimpleTaskConfiguration] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration; factoryMethodName=transactionManager; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]]
2018-01-05 17:13:39.784  WARN 14436 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassEnhancer       : @Bean method ScopeConfiguration.stepScope is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean javadoc for complete details.
2018-01-05 17:13:39.804  WARN 14436 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassEnhancer       : @Bean method ScopeConfiguration.jobScope is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean javadoc for complete details.
2018-01-05 17:13:39.943  INFO 14436 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.task.batch.configuration.TaskBatchAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.task.batch.configuration.TaskBatchAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e6554726] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-01-05 17:13:39.952  INFO 14436 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$60e59b9a] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-01-05 17:13:40.005  INFO 14436 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.task.batch.listener.BatchEventAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.task.batch.listener.BatchEventAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2eab5129] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-01-05 17:13:40.955  INFO 14436 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-01-05 17:13:40.971  INFO 14436 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-01-05 17:13:40.972  INFO 14436 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.23
2018-01-05 17:13:41.201  INFO 14436 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-01-05 17:13:41.202  INFO 14436 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3116 ms
2018-01-05 17:13:41.540  INFO 14436 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2018-01-05 17:13:41.544  INFO 14436 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-05 17:13:41.545  INFO 14436 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-05 17:13:41.545  INFO 14436 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-05 17:13:41.545  INFO 14436 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-05 17:13:42.681  INFO 14436 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/task/schema-h2.sql]
2018-01-05 17:13:42.726  INFO 14436 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executed SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/task/schema-h2.sql] in 45 ms.
2018-01-05 17:13:43.076  INFO 14436 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@9e725a: startup date [Fri Jan 05 17:13:38 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-01-05 17:13:43.170  INFO 14436 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-01-05 17:13:43.172  INFO 14436 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-01-05 17:13:43.206  INFO 14436 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-01-05 17:13:43.207  INFO 14436 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-01-05 17:13:43.314  INFO 14436 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-01-05 17:13:43.415  INFO 14436 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql]
2018-01-05 17:13:43.435  INFO 14436 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executed SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql] in 20 ms.
2018-01-05 17:13:43.592  INFO 14436 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-01-05 17:13:43.603  INFO 14436 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 0
2018-01-05 17:13:43.721  INFO 14436 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-01-05 17:13:43.725  INFO 14436 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner   : Running default command line with: []
2018-01-05 17:13:43.730  INFO 14436 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: H2
2018-01-05 17:13:43.913  INFO 14436 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
2018-01-05 17:13:43.961  INFO 14436 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=job]] launched with the following parameters: [{}]
2018-01-05 17:13:43.972  INFO 14436 --- [           main] o.s.c.t.b.l.TaskBatchExecutionListener   : The job execution id 1 was run within the task execution 1
2018-01-05 17:13:43.981  INFO 14436 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [jobStep1]
2018-01-05 17:13:43.992  INFO 14436 --- [           main] com.jwt.spring.batch.JobConfiguration    : Job was run
2018-01-05 17:13:43.998  INFO 14436 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=job]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
2018-01-05 17:13:44.003  INFO 14436 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@9e725a: startup date [Fri Jan 05 17:13:38 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-01-05 17:13:44.004  INFO 14436 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 0
2018-01-05 17:13:44.005  INFO 14436 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2018-01-05 17:13:44.278  INFO 14436 --- [           main] c.jwt.spring.batch.ScdfBatchApplication  : Started ScdfBatchApplication in 6.956 seconds (JVM running for 9.208)
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing Please add timestamp to name of the Job to make it unique everytime its being run.

Secondly, you should use task-launcher or stream to launch your task run more than once.

- Launch it using TriggerTask; with this you could either choose to launch it with fixedDelay or via a cron expression

Finally if you wanted job to be running based on some event then create and deploy your spring batch job as stream rather than deploying as task. What type of stream depends upon your requirement whether it is processor or sink. As per the details in your query, its more kind of processor hence reference examples from spring cloud stream related to processor, have pasted a sample processor application code. 
Please refer https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/transform

Comment: Please share me some link if it is available with you.

Comment: Use below command on dataflowshell which creates  stream and launch timer  task at regular intervals. stream create foo --definition "triggertask --uri=maven://org.springframework.cloud.task.app:timestamp-task:jar:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT --fixed-delay=5 | tasklauncher-local"

Comment: above command copied from https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/tree/master/tasklauncher/spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-tasklauncher-local

Also refer examples which spring cloud stream team has provided to all of us, most of them are very well explained
 https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples

Answer (score 0):

Please this post. You need to use the RunIdIncrementer in your job.

[Spring Batch Item Reader is executing only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30165680/spring-batch-item-reader-is-executing-only-once/47998827#47998827)